# How to create an unit test for UncontrolledTooltip from reactstrap that does not handle state management directly?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, reactstrap

I implemented simple `UncontrolledTooltip` from `reactstrap`. The doc (https://reactstrap.github.io/components/tooltips/) says

> uncontrolled component can provide the functionality wanted without the need to manage/control the state of the component

If I want to implement an unit test (e.g. `jest + enzyme`) for testing its state as either open or close, how can I create a unit test without manually tinkering with state value? Is this possible to achieve it? It seems only possible with regular `Tooltip` component but I like to hear advice from seasoned engineers.

[Update]:

Upon request I include here tooltip and unit test I am trying to execute. At the moment, I want to simulate `hover` on the tooltip however `mockHover.mock.calls.length` returns as `0` which I interpret as mock function was not triggered.

Here is my Tooltip.

```
import React from 'react';
import { UncontrolledTooltip } from 'reactstrap';    

export default class MyTooltip extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { metaData, wg } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <UncontrolledTooltip placement="bottom" trigger={'hover'} target={wg}>
          {metaData}
        </UncontrolledTooltip>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my unit test that use `jest and enzyme`:

```
describe('<MyTooltip />', () => {
  it('Tooltip unit test', () => {    
    const mockHover = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyTooltip trigger={mockHover} />);
    expect(wrapper.find(UncontrolledTooltip));
    wrapper.find(UncontrolledTooltip).simulate('hover');
    expect(mockHover.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

Comment: how does it work? does it subscribe to event on its own through `addEventListener`? can you provide minimal working example of such a component?

Comment: I included minimal working example for a tooltip and unit test I am working on. Ty for your time looking into this question.

Comment: My deviated question is how can I simulate mouse hover on ```UncontrolledTooltip```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few important things to start from:

1. `UncontrolledTooltip` is part of 3rd party package so you won't test it explicitly. 
   Instead you better focus on testing your wrapper around `UncontrolledTooltip`.
2. `simulate` is nothing related to events browser's system. It's just a syntax sugar to do `props().onHover(...)`. So if target component has such a prop - and it's a callback-function - it will be called. If there is no such a prop - it would be up to `defaultProps` what's going on. Anyway nothing like 'emulating mouse cursor over the element'.
3. `shallow()` will stop rendering at level of `UncontrolledTooltip`(its internals will not be rendered)

Keeping that in mind I see you able only:

1. your component finally renders `UncontrolledTooltip` with expected constant prop values
2. both `metaData` and `wg` props are passed down to `UncontrolledTooltip`

   ```
   it('renders UncontrolledTooltips under the hood', () => {
     const wg = '1';
     const metaData = (<span>2</span>);
     const wrapper = shallow(<MyTooltip wg={wg} metaData={metaData} />);
     const innerTooltip = wrapper.find(UncontrolledTooltip);
     /* 
     I don't validate `find(UncontrolledTooltip).toHaveLength(1)`
     since assertion on `.find(..).props()` would throw exception otherwise
     */ 
     expect(innerTooltip.props().placement).toEqual('bottom');
     expect(innerTooltip.props().trigger).toEqual('hover');
     expect(innerTooltip.props().wg).toEqual(wg);
     expect(innerTooltip.props().metaData).toEqual(metaData);
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation which greatly enhances my shallow understanding on jest and enzyme. I accepted your reply as an answer b/c it verifies mouse `hover`  on TT I believe however for comparing `wg` and `metaData` I was keep getting `Comparing two different types of values. Expected String but received undefined`. Any idea what might have caused it?

Comment: oh..I forgot to mention `wg` and `metaData` would be dynamically generated for its values.

Comment: as for "expected string but get undefined" it means some of `expect().toEqual('...')` fails, right? so test case also fails. so some prop is not set at all for `UncontrolledTooltip`. at least it looks most probable reason, you need to pay attention to error message to figure out at what line it happens.

Comment: did not get point on "dynamically generating", but for unit testing it's typical to have static values in both input parameters and expected results. if you have some external source(like say `Math.random`) you may and probably should [mock that](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules) to use the same values each test run.